# Input validation with scanf()

Tags: c, validation, input, integer

I have a task to enter a certain type of input - rgb ( x, y, z ), where x,y,z represents rgb color(integer).
And I need to check it so that it is entered exactly like this. There is an example of an input:

```
    rgb         (  0  ,   255  ,   0   )
```

with a lot of spaces, this is a valid input, but it gives me that it is not.
My peace of code:

```
if (scanf("rgb ( %d, %d, %d )", &x,&y,&z) != 3 || x > 255
        || y > 255 || z > 255 || x < 0 || y < 0 || z < 0){
        printf("Wrong input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

There should also be a valid input if you remove all the spaces, just the form should remain - rgb(three intehger numbers with coma). And also it should be okay with a lot of spaces, like above.
What am I doing wrong in the validation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Put a space before each comma in the format string, to mop up the spaces before the commas in the input.

Comment: Use spaces in the format string anywhere you want it to consume spaces.  You forgot them before the commas, so as a result it doesn't allow spaces there.  You can also add a leading space if you want it to consume leading spaces.

Comment: And at the start, so `" rgb (%d ,%d ,%d )"`. I took out those before `%d` to show that `%d` filters whitespace automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put space before each comma or use space in the format string anywhere you want it to consume spaces